# How to subscribe on variable changes?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have declared the following variable:

```
public filter: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort = {};
```

How to subscribe on changes(listen object filter)?

I tried this:

```
private filter: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort = {};
private filterChanges: BehaviorSubject<IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort> = new BehaviorSubject(this.filter);

this.filterChanges.subscribe((model) => {
    console.log(model);
});
```

Is it okay?

My final code:

```
public _filter: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort = {};
private filterChanges: BehaviorSubject<IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort> = new BehaviorSubject(this._filter);

  this.filter = {a: 1, b: 2}

  set filter(value: any) {
    this._filter = value;
    this.filterChanges.next(this._filter);
  }

  get filter() {
    return this.filterChanges.asObservable();
  }
```

Subscribe on:

```
this.filter.subscribe(model => {
   console.log(model);
});
```

Changes I make from form:

```
[(ngModel)]="_filter.teacherId"
```

Comment: What is your end goal? There might be a better way than subscribing to a change event (which usually can be an expensive operation as it could be called many times)

Comment: Goal is to detect any changes in `filter` object and decide what to do next with that

Comment: **Subject/BehaviorSubject** allows you to both publish as well as listen to changes. You can `this.filterChanges.next(data)` to publish any change and `this.filterChanges.subscribe((data)=>this.filter = data)` to listen any changes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a setter

```
private _filter: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort = {};
set filter(value) {
  this.doSomethingOnVariableChange(value);
  this._filter = value;
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
this.filter = 'x';
```

And your function `doSomethingOnVariableChange` will be called with `'x'`.

With an observable :

```
private _filter: IFilterWeekScheduleClassShort = {};
private _filter$ = new BehaviorSubject(this._filter);
set filter(value) {
  this._filter = value;
  this._filter$.next(this._filter);
}
get filter() {
  return this._filter$.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Like a way, but I want to use Observer

Comment: It looks not beauty, is it okay? Maybe I have chosen wrong and unlogic way?

Comment: Well it looks "not beauty" because I have kept your variables for easy access to it. You can simply keep a single BehaviorSubject if you want, that would be the second line of the code I have added.

Comment: Okay, but where to show changes I mean console.log(this._filter)? in `get filter()`?

Comment: Or subscribe on `_filter$`?

Comment: It works, but when I subscribe I get not object value but: `source: BehaviorSubject`

Comment: To show changes, do it in `set` since you want to show changes when you **set** a value. When you subscribe, it is on `this.filter`, with `this.filter.subscribe(value => console.log(value))`

Comment: Maybe subscribe on `_filter$ `?

Comment: Nope. I mean, you can, but the getter is made specifically for that.

Comment: I still get not object but: `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: BehaviorSubject}` when subscribed: `this.filter.subscribe(model => {
      console.log(model);
    });`

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `this._filter$.next(this._filter);`, and not `this._filter$.next(this._filter$);` ?

Comment: Sure, what about: `get filter() {
    return this.filterChanges.asObservable(this._filter);
  }`?

Comment: "Make a setter".. excellent, sometimes I just don't see the simple approach, which in my case was sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closes that what you want to get is using `scan()`:

```
const filterChanges$ = new Subject()
const defaultFilter = {}

const filter$ = filterChanges$
  .pipe(
    scan((acc, mergeFilter) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        ...mergeFilter,
      }
    }, defaultFilter)
  )

filter$.subscribe(console.log);

filterChanges$.next({ name: 'abc' })
filterChanges$.next({ num: 42 })
filterChanges$.next({ name: 'xyz' })
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-ngqkzv?file=index.ts

This will output:

```
{name: "abc"}
{name: "abc", num: 42}
{name: "xyz", num: 42}
```

Some time ago I made a small wrapper around `window.Proxy` called `rxjs-observable-object` that lets you wrap any object and then listen to changes on it (https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-ds#object):

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ObservableObject } from 'rxjs-observable-object';

const defaultFilter = {}
const { proxy, events } = new ObservableObject(defaultFilter);

const filter$ = events.onSet
  .pipe(
    map(({ target }) => target)
  )

filter$.subscribe(console.log);

proxy['name'] = 'abc';
proxy['num'] = 42;
proxy['name'] = 'xyz';
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-hojjkk?file=index.ts

However, `rxjs-observable-object` is a little outdated now and requires `rxjs-comapt` package installed as well.

The output for both examples is the same.